# Unable to instantiate Firefox using Marionette driver over Selenium and C#. os error

Tags: selenium, webdriver, ui-automation, firefox-marionette

Could someone please help me with the following issue.

While I'm trying to initialize a browser I get the 'os error' exception.

```
var option = new FirefoxOptions();
option.IsMarionette = true;
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(option);

var b = new Browser(driver); // Throws an exception with a message - 'os error'
```

[The screenshot of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9MbC.png)

Plese note, the path to wires.exe is added to the system PATH. Selenium, wires, firefox are of the latest versions. I have tried running using firefox-stable and firefox-developer editions.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added Marionette executable to Path?

Comment: Sure. I've added it to path. The wires starts but the browser not.

Comment: I know you are most likely updated to the latest but what version are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ran into the 'os error' issue when I was trying to get Marionette working. The source of the issue in my case was I was trying to use some NuGet package called 'Mozilla Firefox Webdriver 0.6.0.1' which I believe had a very old version of the (now called) geckodriver.exe.

I downloaded the latest version of the driver from here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
renamed to wires.exe and put in my working directory
then I had to initiate the driver using the following code.

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
Driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

The way you initated the driver was giving me an `entity not found` exception.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe DesiredCapabilities would work.

```
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
   capabilities.SetCapability("marionette", true);
   var driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: actually DesiredCapabilities.Firefox() works, but the tests starts over selenium not marionette. I've checked it by deleting the wires.exe.

Comment: yes, I am facing the same issue. Caps do not start the marionette driver. Anyone has solution for this, please suggest.